# Using U-net in Python with 3-channel input images for image segmentation

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am using [unet](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py) for image segmentation, using the code outlined [herein](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-keras-pipeline-for-image-segmentation-part-1-6515a421157d).

My input images are 256x256x3. while the corresponding segmentation masks are 256x256.

I have changed the size for the input to Unet:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,3)):
```

and get a network with a 256x256x1 layer for the output

```
conv2d_144 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 1)  2           conv2d_143[0][0]
```

See the full architecture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfCtl.jpg).

When I try and run using .fit_generator, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_144 to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

What can I do to fix this? Please let me know what extra information I can give!

Thank you!

PS: I have three classes in the outputs, could that be the reason?

Comment: Can you join what you pass as inputs and expected outputs to your model?

Comment: I think the problem is with your ground-truth image because your model seems to be outputting a 1-band image; you should check if the expected label image is a 3-band image, a few packages read grayscale images with 3-bands even though they could be 1-banded.

Comment: @R0bots change the last layer dimensions from `conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)` to `conv10 = Conv2D(3, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)` so you have 256x256x3 output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually fixed it by one-hot encoding my segmentation masks and changing the activation function of the last layer to softmax, with a filtersize to match the number of classes!

https://github.com/MKeel1ng/MULTI-CHANNEL-UNET

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide if want an RGB or grayscale input for your images:
Either convert your images to grayscale or change the conv layer. Another option would be to flatten the 256x256x3 input to a one dimension and use that as input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case maintaining RGB as an input is crucial. I've actually fixed it I think by one-hot encoding my segmentation masks and changing the activation function of the last layer to softmax, with a filtersize to match the number of classes!